# Combinatorics - Digital Clock Problem

Tags: combinatorics

Assume that I have digital clock (24h format) and I must find in how many times this clock showing nondecreasing sequence.

**Literal task:**

> Every couple of three couples of digits (hh, mm, ss) separately make
>   non-decreasing sequence and number of minutes and seconds are differ
>   in parity.

i dont understand task and i dont know relations between digits and pairs of numbers.

but I need some math formula how to count this possibilities. Any idea?

Comment: In the text you say you want a non-decreasing sequence, but in the formula you mix $\lt$ and $\le$. Please clarify.

Comment: @joriki "every couple of three couples of digits (hh, mm, ss) separately make non-decreasing sequence and number of minutes and seconds are differ in parity" - this is literal task

Comment: Well why didn't you write that, then, if that's what you want to do? You didn't even mention parity. Please edit the question so that it can be undertstood without having to read the comments. Also, I don't see what in that description corresponds to your $\lt$ relations.

Comment: @joriki so right sequence is **h1 <= h2 <= m1 <= m2 <= s1 <= s2** ?

Comment: I don't see where you're taking that from. It's not entirely clear because of the partially ungrammatical translation (perhaps you could post it in your native language?), but it still seems sufficiently clear that "separately" refers to pairs of digits separately and not to comparisons across pairs.

Comment: The literal task you've added is ungrammatical. Is this a faithful rendition of what you mean? "Each pair of the three pairs of digits (hh, mm, ss) separately forms a non-decreasing sequence, and the number of minutes and the number of seconds differ in parity."

Comment: Why has your count of $303$ not changed? It would seem that with the new definition of the problem you should get a new count. Also, if you write more about how you counted, that might throw some light both on where you went wrong and on how the task is to be interpreted.

Comment: @joriki yes, i mean what you say, but i dont know now what reations are between digits ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm basing my answer on this reformulation of the problem that I posted in a comment: "Each pair of the three pairs of digits (hh, mm, ss) separately forms a non-decreasing sequence, and the number of minutes and the number of seconds differ in parity."

If the first digit of a two-digit number is $j$, there are $j$ options for the second digit to be less than the first. So if the first digit can go up to $k$, the number of decreasing two-digit numbers is

$$
\sum_{j=0}^kj=\frac{k(k+1)}2\;.
$$

For the hours, $k=2$, so there are $3$ decreasing numbers, and hence $24-3=21$ non-decreasing numbers. For the minutes and seconds, $k=5$, so there are $15$ decreasing numbers, and hence $60-15=45$ non-decreasing numbers. There are $30$ odd and $30$ even numbers from $0$ to $59$, and of the decreasing ones $1+3+5=9$ are even and $2+4=6$ are odd, so of the $45$ non-decreasing numbers $30-9=21$ are even and $30-6=24$ are odd. Then the total number of time displays in which each of the three two-digit numbers is non-decreasing and the minutes and seconds have different parity is

$$
2\cdot21\cdot21\cdot24=21168\;,
$$

where the factor $2$ accounts for the fact that we can have either odd minutes and even seconds or vice versa.

Comment: why there are 6 possibilities for hours? i thought that these are possibilities for hours - 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23

Comment: @MLN96: Sorry, for some reason I counted non-increasing sequences -- will correct as soon as I can.

Comment: @MLN96: I've corrected the answer; sorry about the careless mistake.

Comment: thank you very much for willingness :)